# Cannot use Java in a SLURM job on an HPC

Tags: java, bash, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I am trying to run a simple script on a Linux HPC, where I am looping over a number of RNA-seq files and want to call fastQC, a Java based program, on each of the files.
In the script I'm calling a wrapper script that runs the Java fastQC-program.

The script I wrote is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -t 00:30:00
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --mail-type=end
#SBATCH --clusters=serial
#SBATCH --partition=serial_std
#SBATCH --mem=6gb

echo "Starting to run fastQC..."

FILENAMES_TXT=*filenames_path*/small_test_sample_filenames.txt
DIR_DATA=*data_directory*
IPPG=*roote_directory on the cluster dss*

FILENAMES_PATH=$IPPG/$FILENAMES_TXT
DATA_PATH=$IPPG/$DIR_DATA

LINES=$(cat $FILENAMES_PATH)

for LINE in $LINES
do
        FILE=$DATA_PATH/$LINE
        echo $FILE

        *home_directory_path*/FastQC/fastqc $FILE
done

echo "fastQC is done!"
```

When I submit this job using **sbatch**, the SLURM error message is:
*Can't exec "java": No such file or directory*

Running the script on a single sample on the HPC-Login-Node worked fine, so I think the script published by fastQC is fine, and the problem only arises, when the script is submitted to the SLURM system with *sbatch*.

Apparently, the fastQC-script cannot find JAVA in the SLURM system, after it was called in my Bash-script.
Can anybody with HPC / SLURM experience tell me, how to import Java into the environment when submitting a job (I am not sure if that question is phrased correctly, but I hope somebody can understand)?

Comment: This is the error that `sbatch` returns???

Comment: It's the error message that's printed into the slurm-xxx.out file, that's produced by every slurm job.

Comment: Then you just need to make sure that `java` is available on `$PATH`. And any other enviroment variable needed. How do you "load" java in your interactive environment?

Comment: Put this at the beginning of your script `java -version` and share us the result

Comment: Adding 'java -version' to the script produced this error message:
*/var/slurmd-serial/job2522565/slurm_script: line 11: java: command not found*

@Poshi: I tried using 'module load java' before, but also only yielded an error.

Comment: @Poshi: On my login node, 'java' is in '$PATH' under '/usr/bin'. I think that's why it worked on the login node, but the path environment seems to be different on the compute nodes of the SLURM system.

Comment: Then, you have to configure your environment in the jobs for any of your installed java versions. How to do it? Ask your administrator.

Comment: Will do and post the result once I have an answer, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found through the system administrator:

`module load openjdk`